How can I get the bonding curve address for a pump.fun token?
I know that I can go through transactions and get the bonding curve address from buy/sell/create functions but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it through account info or something easier? I'm using Node.js, btw.

const [bondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("bonding-curve"), new PublicKey('MINT_ADDRESS').toBytes()], PUMP_PROGRAM_ADDRESS);

Thanks!
Do you know by any chance how to get the associated bonding curve as well?

Figured it out myself, the associated bonding curve is the token account of the bonding curve

@Richy is this on the right track?     const [assoc] =  PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("associated-bonding-curve"), TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), bonding.toBuffer(), BASE_MINT.toBuffer()], PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM);

Got it     const [associatedBonding] =  PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([bonding.toBuffer(), TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), BASE_MINT.toBuffer()], ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID);

Here is a answer with a complete bondingCurve and associatedBondingCurve:
const {
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
} = require("@solana/spl-token");

const PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM = new PublicKey("6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P");
const PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT = new PublicKey("Ce6TQqeHC9p8KetsN6JsjHK7UTZk7nasjjnr7XxXp9F1")

const mint_account = Keypair.generate();  
  
const [bondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [
    Buffer.from("bonding-curve"),  
    mint_account.publicKey.toBuffer()
  ], 
  PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM);

const [associatedBondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [
    bondingCurve.toBuffer(), 
    PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT.toBuffer(),
    mint_account.publicKey.toBuffer(), 
  ], 
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID);

I exactly used it like this in my code ;)

Some changes, to get the bondingcurve address.
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey, SystemProgram, Keypair, Transaction, sendAndConfirmTransaction } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const {
ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} = require("@solana/spl-token");
const PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM = new PublicKey("6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P");
const PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT = new PublicKey("Ce6TQqeHC9p8KetsN6JsjHK7UTZk7nasjjnr7XxXp9F1")
const mint_account =  new PublicKey('Gvs35ryrM3dDZMbu4iX7L3T2obmUaLQTaFjHkS6ypump').toBytes()
const [bondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
[
Buffer.from("bonding-curve"),
mint_account
],  PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM);
const [associatedBondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
[
bondingCurve.toBuffer(),
PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT.toBuffer(),
mint_account,
],
ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID);
console.log("Bonding Curve", bondingCurve)
console.log("Assct Prgm", associatedBondingCurve);

Here's the version that worked for me, taken from the ideas of people posting above :
import { Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';

const PUMP_PROGRAM_ADDRESS = new PublicKey("6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P");

function getBondingCurveAddress(mintAddress) {
    const [bondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("bonding-curve"), mintAddress.toBytes()], PUMP_PROGRAM_ADDRESS);
    return bondingCurve;
}

function getAssociatedBondingCurveAddress(bondingCurveAddress, mintAddress) {
    const [associatedBondingCurve] = 
    PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([bondingCurveAddress.toBuffer(), TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), mintAddress.toBuffer()], ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID);
    return associatedBondingCurve;
}```

